# Some questions about Peano and Picard

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have some question regarding the Peano and Picard theorems.

It started with this exercise:

Prove that there exists a solution near the initial value for
$y^{\prime}=(x-y)^{5/4},\,y(4)=4$ and state if the solution near that point is unique.

I believe that we can't really conclude by using Peano's theorem the existence of a solution and that's because we can't find any rectangle under $y=x$ that contains the point $(4,4)$ in which $(x-y)^{5/4}$ is continuous.

I know I am wrong, but can someone explain me why?

The confusion started when I read at some online notes here that the problem 
$y^{\prime}=(y-x)^{1/2},\,y(a)=b$ is guaranteed to have a solution ONLY if $a>b$, it states that at $a=b$ any rectangle will "catch" points for which $x>y$ and thus we can't take $a\geq b$ . 
(http://web.math.rochester.edu/people/faculty/edummit/docs/calc2_5_introduction_to_differential_equations.pdf at page $4$)

According to this, I shouldn't be able to prove that there exists a solution near point (4,4) since $a=b=4$. Can someone explain to me why I am wrong? So after all, is there any rectangle which contains $(4,4)$ in which the function is continuous? If so would be it like this? http://sketchtoy.com/67691139 ?
I am so confused, I am not sure if I even explained it properly :S .

Thanks for reading my (probably) stupid question.

Answer (score 2):

The trouble with the differential equation as stated is that $(x-y)^{5/4}$ is not real if $y > x$.  So let's change the differential equation to one that works:
$$ y' = |x-y|^{5/4},\ y(4) = 4$$
This one is perfectly good: continuous and Lipschitz in a neighbourhood of $(4,4)$, so it has a unique solution $y^*(x)$ in a neighbourhood of $x=4$.
Now all you need to do is prove that $y^*(x) \le x$  for $x \ge 4$,  so that $y^*$ actually solves your original differential equation.